# What alternatives are there to Fiddler debugging proxy?

Tags: software-recommendation, proxy

I'm looking for a good and famous web debugging proxy that can logs all HTTP(S) traffic. Like a [fiddler for Windows](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). I found that it doesn't work on Ubuntu.

So is there any one for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> [NetTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nettool/) is a developer tool for monitoring and manipulating
>   application-level network messages, particularly useful for debugging
>   web applications and web services. There are two components to
>   NetTool: the HTTP Client, and the TCP Tunnel.<sup>1</sup>
>
> [Paros](http://www.parosproxy.org/) is for web application security assessment.  It is free of
>   charge and completely written in Java. Through Paros's proxy nature,
>   all HTTP and HTTPS data between server and client, including cookies
>   and form fields, can be intercepted and modified.<sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nettool/)</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Paroproxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Fiddler is now available for linux and Mac through its Mono port. All instructions available [here](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono)

Comment: But does not work in Yosemite. Does not eve launch

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu, also doesn't even launch.

Comment: For me launches on debian 9.5 but does not capture anything

Answer (score 6):

I find [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) really handy. It is not Open Source but it is written in Java (works everywhere) and it has [community edition](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload). Supports HTTPS, other features are called [Essential manual tools](https://portswigger.net/burp#essential-manual-tools)

Comment: Why -1? You can setup Burp Suite as debug proxy...

Comment: Most probably, because the link you gave doesn't indicate that it runs under Ubuntu. Also paid software raises spam flags on many people here. Can't blame them though, Ask Ubuntu is targeted by spammers.

Comment: Ok,I see. Burp suite is not Open Source but it is written in Java and it has [free edition](http://portswigger.net/burp/download.html). Even for HTTPS.

Comment: Please update the link in your answer.

Comment: @thewebjackal updated :)

Answer (score 6):

You can try [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

I've been using it a while and it works well.

Comment: To use it on Ubuntu `16.04` you need to install Java Oracle `1.8`. Check out [this link](https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/install-java-jre-jdk-on-ubuntu-16-04/) on how to do it.

Comment: @czerasz I don't why my newly-installed Charles does not capture any traffic. It just doesn't work at all. I use `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` and lastest Java JDK

Answer (score 4):

[NetTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nettool/) is one the best tools as Suggested by [Mitch](https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch)

You should also try out [Webscarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Webscarab). WebScarab is a framework for analysing applications that communicate using the HTTP and HTTPS protocols.

Comment: But to use it as proxy I need to make a tunel for each host, it is not a good thing for request debug in pratice

Answer (score 0):

I used the free tool wire shark. https://www.wireshark.org/.  Good alternative!

Comment: @Aditya https://www.wireshark.org/
You wrote more than 20 words and still don't put the link. I think the link is not important to you, just blame other users. What do you expect from a new user? reading the faq? Don't make me laugh :D

Comment: Wireshark is **NOT** a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why nobody mentioned good old [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/), which is a browser addon available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo).
It allows you to view and modify http headers.

Answer (score 0):

[Proxy.app](http://www.proxyapp.io/)

[Betwixt](https://github.com/kdzwinel/betwixt) - based on Chrome DevTools interface

Some additional options located on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617536/http-debugging-proxy-for-linux-and-mac).